# SASS: @use doesn't allow to access variables from namespace

Tags: variables, sass, module, namespaces

I'm trying to access variables from a different module via @use. Even though I use namespace prefix, I still receive the following error:

```
Compilation Error
Error: Invalid CSS after "...round: branding": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$primary;"
        on line 18 of sass/Users/bjorngrundtal/Desktop/sass/css/style.sass
>>     background: branding.$primary;
```

Here is **style.sass**

```
@use 'abstracts/branding' as branding

@mixin center($text-align: center)
    margin: 0 auto
    text-align: $text-align

%nospace
    padding: 0
    margin: 0

body
    @extend %nospace

header
    @extend %nospace
    width: 100vw
    height: 32vh
    background: branding.$primary
    h1
        color: branding.$bright
    p
        color: branding.$secondary

footer
    @extend header
```

And variables in **abstracts/_branding.sass**

```
$primary: #ff00ff
$secondary: #00fff0
$bright: #fff
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong will be highly appreciated

I'm suing VSC with the Live SASS extension.

Comment: Just an assumption: the variable definitions are not ending with a trailing `;`